# How to setup Trac to run at / with Lighttpd on a subdomain

Tags: trac, lighttpd, fastcgi

I have the following config in my lighttpd.conf:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "trac.domain.tld" {
    server.document-root = "/usr/home/daniels/trac/htdocs/"
    fastcgi.server       = ( "/trac" =>
                             ( "trac" =>
                               ( "socket" => "/tmp/trac-fastcgi.sock",
                                 "bin-path" => "/usr/home/daniels/trac/cgi-bin/trac.fcgi",
                                 "check-local" => "disable",
                                 "bin-environment" =>
                                 ( "TRAC_ENV" => "/usr/home/daniels/trac" )
                               )
                             )
                           )
}
```

And it runs at trac.domain.tld/trac.
How can i make it to run at trac.domain.tld/ so i will have trac.domain.tld/wiki, trac.domain.tld/timeline, etc instead of trac.domain.tld/trac/wiki, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for "For top level setup: ..." [here](http://trac.lighttpd.net/trac/wiki/HowToSetupTrac).

Answer (score 1):

Just change "/trac" to "/" in fastcgi.server